# Is there a way to define a common env variable in aws lambda layer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I use serverless framework and I have multilple aws node.js lambdas that share the same layer. I want to define an ENV variable for all of them-is there a way to put that common ENV variable into the layer's `serverless.yml`? Or do I have to go and put it in each `serverles.yml` files separately?

Comment: Put them in a common file and import that common file into each deployment's serverless.yml template? See https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-other-files

Comment: @Capaj were you able to find a satisfactory solution for environment vars in layers?

Comment: @trdavidson yeah we're using serverless-dotenv-plugin and it works fine for our fleet of lambdas

Comment: Thanks @Capaj will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with env variables in my lambdas i use this plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dotenv-plugin

It looks for a .env file use it as a reference to your env variables.

```
plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
```

Hope it helps.